# Android How to set a View under Textview which width will be same as set text width?

Tags: android, android-layout, view, textview

Hi I want to set a View under textview. But I need the View width will be dynamically change when i will set text in textview.

Like this image:-

[image]

Need some help how can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
yourTextView.setPaintFlags(yourTextView.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
yourTextView.setText(yourString)
```

or

```
SpannableString content = new SpannableString(yourString);
content.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, yourString.length(), 0);
yourTextView.setText(content);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works for me. Thanks again.